# Silverlight - Rich Textbox

Tags: silverlight

I am using the Silver light Richtext box.  All is working fine on my dev machine but when I publish it to IIs (IIS6 not sure if this matters)  the mark-up is being  displaying rather than formatted text.  Again every thing is working on my PC so the code is correct.

This is being displayed

```
<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface"
               Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal"
               FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="0"
               LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
        <Run>trends including: </Run>
```

(NOTE: Code formatted for readability - there are no spaces in the original).

Comment: Now that the code is visible I can see that you've missed off the closing `</Paragraph>` and `</Section>`. Is this really missing?

Comment: I sorry I just did not paste all of it.  Again this application inculding the RichTextbox is working fine on my dev PC.  I am presuming there is something missing on the server but I cant figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6.0 needs to have manually configured MIME types in order to run Silverlight properly:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/

Comment: Hi Yes I have this already done.   The rest of the apllication is working fine just the rich text box is not displaying forrectly.